# Modifing Query using object model in custom CoreResults webpart

Tags: search

Where is the correct place to change the query before query is executed in a custom CoreResults webpart.

ex.

```
//QueryManager.UserQuery = query.ToString();
runtime.KeywordQueryObject.QueryText = query.ToString();
```

AddSortOrder in CoreResultsDatasourceView does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding GetXpathNavigator in my custom CoreResultsWebpart. This event fires in a late stage, causing the query change not to be overwritten. First I tried to override AddSortOrder in my View, the changes to the query was then lost. Changing sorting worked in AddSortOrder though.

The code I added to GetXPathNavigator was:

```
QueryManager.UserQuery = query.ToString();
```

As mamoo noted overriding SetPropertiesOnQdra() will probably work as well. Allthough I have not tested, but will do at work on Monday.

Som offical guidance/best practices on SharePoint Search from Microsoft would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've succesfully modified my query (but I'm using Fast Search, don't know how much it does change) overriding SetPropertiesOnQdra() in the extended CoreResultsDatasourceView inner class.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointsearch/thread/dc3a378d-5ad3-47f2-8bb7-526fc225680a) may be helpful to you.